# For how much time Android stores data into cache? Or, what is the max data size stored?

Tags: android, image, caching

Right now, I'm working with this following method to load images:

```
public static Drawable loadCachedImage(String strUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        Object response = connection.getContent();
        if (response instanceof Bitmap) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)response;
            return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        } else {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) connection.getContent();
            return Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

AFAIK, it uses Android's default cache. So, I'd like to know for how much time it stores a given app information (or what is the max data size stored). Is it a settings configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Scope of cache its depending on your for default cache storage as we know many another application are available in market to clear your cache for another purpose of usage. Or if user can manually clear cache from the `Settings->Application->Manage application->your app`
in this display total size of your application.